# VB.NET calling Fortran: how to fix PInvoke exception?

Tags: vb.net, fortran

In working up a simple example of VB calling fortran, I'm getting two errors depending on what approach I try to take.  While the following small reproducible example below is simple, it is a precursor to a much larger problem.

The primary goal of this simple example is to adjust the value of an argument passed to the Fortran code (in this case, "SUMMATION") and then use the returned (and adjusted) value in VB.

I first offer the simple fortran code, then show the two variations of VB code used to call it along with the error message each approach results in.

**The Fortran code called by VB:**

```
SUBROUTINE MFNWT_RUN(KSTP,KPER,SUMMATION) 

    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: MFNWT_RUN
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: "MFNWT_RUN" :: MFNWT_RUN

    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER, Intent(in) :: KPER, KSTP
    INTEGER, Intent(inout) :: SUMMATION

    INTEGER kkper, kkstp
    INTEGER add_em_up

    kkper = KPER
    kkstp = KSTP

    add_em_up = kkper + kkstp

    SUMMATION = add_em_up 

END SUBROUTINE
```

**The calling VB code (first approach):**

```
Imports System.Collections
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data

Module Module1

    <DllImport("example_fortran_directory.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Function MFNWT_RUN(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer, ByRef Divs As Integer)  'ref bool AdvFlwRdr
    End Function

    ' Private Declare Sub MFNWT_RUN Lib "example_fortran_directory.dll" Alias "MFNWT_RUN" (<[In](), Out()> ByRef A As Integer, ByRef B As Integer, ByRef C As Integer)
    'Declare Sub MFNWT_RUN Lib "example_fortran_directory" (ByRef A As Integer, ByRef B As Integer, ByRef C As Integer)

    Sub Main()
        Dim first As Integer
        Dim second As Integer

        Dim answer As Integer

        first = 6
        second = 7
        answer = 0
        Call MFNWT_RUN(first, second, answer)

        MsgBox(answer)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Gives the error:

[image]

If instead I try and 'wire-up' the call to the Fortran DLL a bit differently (comment out the DllImport code and uncomment the declare code), I get a different error.

**The calling VB code (second approach):**

```
Imports System.Collections
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data

Module Module1

    ' Private Declare Sub MFNWT_RUN Lib "example_fortran_directory.dll" Alias "MFNWT_RUN" (<[In](), Out()> ByRef A As Integer, ByRef B As Integer, ByRef C As Integer)
    Declare Sub MFNWT_RUN Lib "example_fortran_directory" (ByRef A As Integer, ByRef B As Integer, ByRef C As Integer)

    Sub Main()
        Dim first As Integer
        Dim second As Integer

        Dim answer As Integer

        first = 6
        second = 7
        answer = 0
        Call MFNWT_RUN(first, second, answer)

        MsgBox(answer)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Gives the following exception:

[image]

This second approach works - meaning if I acknowledge the error I can move past it, but I would prefer to fix the underlying issue if someone can direct me how to do so? The larger problem I'm aiming to address will be making thousands of calls to Fortran from VB, so it would seem vital that I fix the stack imbalance error the right way (and not just turn off the warning message).

---

Appending another attempt that also resulted in the PInvokeStackImbalance error.

**First the fortran:**

```
   SUBROUTINE MFNWT_RUN(KSTP,KPER,SUMMATION)

    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, ALIAS: 'MFNWT_RUN' :: MFNWT_RUN
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: KSTP
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: KPER
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: SUMMATION

    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER, value :: KPER, KSTP
    INTEGER, value :: SUMMATION

    INTEGER kkper, kkstp
    INTEGER add_em_up

    kkper = KPER
    kkstp = KSTP

    add_em_up = kkper + kkstp

    SUMMATION = add_em_up 

END SUBROUTINE MFNWT_RUN
```

**And the calling VB:**

```
Imports System.Collections
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data

Module Module1

Private Declare Sub MFNWT_RUN Lib "example_fortran_directory.dll" Alias "MFNWT_RUN" (<[In](), Out()> ByRef A As Integer, ByRef B As Integer, ByRef C As Integer)

Sub Main()
    Dim first As Integer
    Dim second As Integer

    Dim answer As Integer

    first = 6
    second = 7
    answer = 0
    Call MFNWT_RUN(first, second, answer)

    MsgBox(answer)

End Sub

End Module
```

This approach also ended in the PInvokeStackImbalance exception being thrown.  First, I'm wondering if this exception is a big deal (i.e., should I simply uncheck it - meaning the code should move on and not warm me when this exception is thrown)?  If it is something that should be fixed (I would assume this to be the case), and you see what my problem is, please help.

Comment: Always mention the compiler you use.  I'm 95% sure that the CallingConvention is wrong, must be Cdecl.  Sub, not Function, arguments passed ByRef.

Comment: If you change the Fortran subroutine to have `INTEGER, Intent(in), value :: KPER, KSTP`, do things improve?

Comment: value should be accompanied by `bind(C)`

Comment: @HansPassant changed CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall to Cdecl as suggested, no change, same error: "Pinvoke restriction: cannot return variants"  Not sure what the second part of your comment was intending to point out?

Comment: @francescalus adding the keyword 'value' to the line in fortran as you suggest, "INTEGER, Intent(in), value :: KPER, KSTP" did not improve things, still get the same unbalanced stack error message

Comment: @VladimirF perhaps you could confirm whether I understood your suggestion, but I added bind(C) to the first line in the fortran code, SUBROUTINE MFNWT_RUN(KSTP,KPER,SUMMATION) bind(C,NAME="MFNWT_RUN")   but am unable to step into the fortran from VB using either approach - "DllImport" or "Declare Sub ..."  The error message is the same in both cases and shown above, "...cannot return variants."  Whereas I could step into the fortran from VB without the BIND(C,...) syntax, the code will return the mentioned error upon attempting to step into the fortran with the BIND() statement, seems worse

Comment: I was saying that C-compatible `value` requires `bind(C)`. Nothing more. Without `bind(C)` it is implemented slightly differently. What is the correct solution I don't know, I don't know any VB.

Comment: Which Fortran compiler?  It matters...

Comment: @IanH Intel Visual Fortran, Microsoft Visual Studio (VB)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using:

```
<DllImport("example_fortran_directory.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Public Sub MFNWT_RUN(ByRef a As Integer, ByRef b As Integer, ByRef c As Integer)  
End Sub
```

Previously I had `Public Function...` instead of `Public Sub...`

I was never able to get the other approach to work:

`Private Declare Sub MFNWT_RUN Lib "example_fortran_directory.dll" Alias "MFNWT_RUN" (<[In](), Out()> ByRef A As Integer, ByRef B As Integer, ByRef C As Integer)`